# Log4J Bridge 1 to 2.17.1 properties are not resolved

Tags: java, properties, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to use the log4j bridge to migrate my application.
I have added the jars and set the configuration properties that are found and loaded.

The first problem was that log4j was not able to find the FileAppender class, I checked  in the bridge jar and it is not present. I took the one from the original 1.2 release and made it compile and it works. I do not know if it is the right way because *the migration tutorial says it should be handled automatically.*

The thing that is causing me problems now is that when log4j loads the properties, they are not resolved correctly; I have

```
log4j.appender.FULL.file            = ${user.home}/${user.name}
```

but it does not work. I also tried

```
log4j.appender.FULL.file            = ${sys:user.home}/${sys:user.name}
```

and

```
log4j.appender.FULL.file            = $${sys:user.home}/$${sys:user.name}
```

without luck

I am using a custom appender that extends FileAppender and the value that is passed is not "expanded" .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I opened a issue on the Log4j tracker and I discovered it was a bug on their end

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3312